# How can I add a button to a window for a Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: c#, button, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to create a Visual Studio Extension and I need to add a button to a specific window. Where am I able to find the "source code" behind this screen in order to add it?

I have tried parsing through different examples and looking through documentation.

```cs
     <Button guid="guidSWO" 
     id="EnableDisableguidSWO" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidSWO" id="MyMenuGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Enable/Disable SWO</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
```

This snip of code displays the button in the menu, but I want to display the button in the Quick Watch Menu

Comment: Image for Reference: https://i.ibb.co/LCGDm5Z/Quick-Watch.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good idea but I'm afraid this behavior is not supported for now.

**Related documents about extending ToolWindow topic:**

[Extend and customize tool windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-and-customizing-tool-windows?view=vs-2019)

[Extend the Output window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-output-window?view=vs-2019)

[Extend the Properties, Task List, Output, and Options windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-properties-task-list-output-and-options-windows?view=vs-2019)

To display the button in the menu, you can easily do this by creating a `custom command template`. And now what you want to is to extend the ToolWindow, you can check the documents above and you'll find you can extend the `Output Window`, `Properties Window` and so on but other windows like `Quick Watch Window` and `Diagnostic Tools Window` are not supported.

We can't extend the `Quick Watch Window` by adding a new button into it,as far as I know it is not supported. The `Quick Watch Window` is different from the `Solution Explorer` or `Output Window`. I would think the `Output window` use `TableControl or TableView or ListView or what` as part of its UI Window, so it's easy to extend it since the VS SDK provides some related API like [IVsOutputWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsoutputwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017). But for `Quick Watch window`, there's no such API in [VS SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to extend its UI.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I am starting my first VS Extension so I am just learning the basics